# How to get customer id from guest checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, guest-checkout, guest

is there any way to get customer id from guest checkout?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information in detail where exactly you need customer id? While placing order on checkout or after placing the order on success page? Yes, you can get it but the ways are different depending upon the case where you need it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get guest email using email you can identify customer id

```
private $session;
protected $_customer;
protected $_storemanager;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_storemanager = $storemanager;
    ....
}

public function getCustomerIdFromQuote() {
     $guestEmail = $this->session->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail();
     $websiteID = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
     $customer = $this->_customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteID)->loadByEmail($guestEmail );
     $customerId = $customer->getId();

}
```